# Implementing sms push in iphone

Tags: iphone, sms, push

Is it possible to invoke an application on reception of an sms. I have created a sample application and it need to be launched when the iphone recieves a particular message. Is it possible to implement this in iphone. If possible, which way shall i do that... pls help...

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387934/iphone-how-to-programmatically-respond-to-sms-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

In the long answer, I believe with version 3.0 you can have your app subscribe to Apple's push notification service. Meaning that you can have your app answer to a notification from Apple that you send. Not quite SMS, but it accomplishes the same thing.

Try this:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html