# How to send sms and receive sms in Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

I want to implement SMS functionality in my application.  Is there any way to do this, or any documentation to implement this functionality?  Can anyone provide sample code for this?

Comment: Hey guys Please gimme a prompt reply.

Comment: I would avoid using "Please gimme a prompt reply" in the future

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387934/iphone-how-to-programmatically-respond-to-sms-messages

Comment: @Shaggy - especially 18 minutes after the question was asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"sms:%@",phonenostring];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message ]];
```

Comment: Then how can I get the sms body to enter the text?

Comment: Apple Documents haven't Specified anywhere that thing...and i don't think so Apple Support that...