# sms notification

Tags: iphone, sms, notifications, message

I am a new iphone application developer.
i am making an application which requires an incoming message notification even if the application is closed.
can anybody tell me how to do that...

Thanks 
Rachit Taneja

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Are you making a replacement for the SMS app (which I think Apple is going to reject for duplicating existing functionality), or are you making an app that relies on a phone receiving SMS messages to function?

Comment: i am making an application in which i want to send an auto message to the address from which i receive sms even if my application is not running.so i want to get the incoming message notification.i am using the CoreTelephony.Framework. but i don't know what to do further.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not implemented a way for your application to listen for incoming text messages or phone calls. iOS only sends out notification about changes to your applications state. For example, when your phone rings in which case your application will receive the applicationWillResignActive (on versions older than iOS4 applicationWillTerminate) notification.

Strictly speaking these are not actual notifications, these methods will be called in your applications delegate.

The closes solution would probably be what Brad suggests in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387934/iphone-how-to-programmatically-respond-to-sms-messages).

Comment: kCTSMSMessageReceivedNotification .this is the notification i get from a forum.But i dont't know how to use this.so if anybody know about this..do tell me.

Comment: this is a jail broken application.so apple has no concerns in this.

Comment: @Rachit, in that case disregard everything i said. This only applies to the standard SDK, i have no experience whatsoever with jailbreak.

Comment: Apps can use CallKit framework to receive incoming calls and make outgoing calls using the native phone UI, but SMS is not supported yet - https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit

Answer (score 0):

You can use core telephony framework but you cant upload your app on app store.Because it's private framework which apple doesn't allow.Using this framework you can send sms upto ios 5 for ios 6 i am looking into this.