# How to prevent iphone sms alert or Intercept sms?

Tags: iphone, sms, jailbreak

When a SMS comes, I don't want sms alert appear in some condition.So what can I do to prevent it? I look into  SBSMSAlertItem,but can't find a method to disable alert. I think I can use mobile subtrate to do this, but which method should I hook?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you take a look at the source code for iPhoneDelivery, you'll find something useful: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-delivery-report/

Comment: @Cyrille  thank you for your answer,but I can't get source from the link you gave.

Comment: The source is here: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-delivery-report/source/checkout

Comment: @Cyrille I get the source finally after modifying https to http. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not stop system's notification in your application. you should refer this SO post

1. [iPhone: How to Programmatically Respond to SMS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387934/iphone-how-to-programmatically-respond-to-sms-messages)

Comment: OP is willing to use mobile subtrate, you would be surprised what you can do with that.

Comment: @DevinGund yes, OP wants to actually prevent the sms alert from popping up and is willing to use jailbreak methods. Mobile subtrate is likely the place to start but I do not have enough experience to answer the question.